# Export Grid view to excel and save excel file to folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to save excel file which export data of grid view. I have written code to export gridview data to excel but I don't know how to save exported file.

Following is my code to export gridview into excel :

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=MyFiles.xls");
Response.Charset = "";
this.EnableViewState = false;
System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw);
gvFiles.RenderControl(htw);
Response.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.End();
```

Comment: You know that you aren't exporting an excel file but a html table? Excel can interpret it, anyway it's not a real excel file. Have a look at [EPPLus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/releases/view/42439).

Comment: Like Tim says use EPPlus - it's a library that will generate actual .xlsx files for you and then you can download these instead. I've used it for a budget monitoring app and it's brilliant.

Comment: what is the DataSource for your grid view ?

Comment: Almost all answer here write a (HtmlTextWriter) string or have Interop code. DO NOT USE EITHER. This will cause you problems later on with DateTime and Decimal formatting. Also Excel will give a warning because you are not generating a "real" Excel file but a HTML page with an .xls extension. Start using a specialized library for creating Excel files, like [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus). [Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47293207/5836671) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39513057/5836671).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this:

```
private void ExportGridView()
{
    System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    // Render grid view control.
    gvFiles.RenderControl(htw);

    // Write the rendered content to a file.
    string renderedGridView = sw.ToString();
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Path\On\Server\ExportedFile.xlsx", renderedGridView);
}
```

Comment: giving me error 
Control 'gvFiles' of type 'GridView' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server. 
:(

Comment: got the ans
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
        {
}

Answer (score 2):

this may help you//

```
protected void exporttoexcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();

    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" attachment" + ".xls");

    Response.Charset = "";

    // If you want the option to open the Excel file without saving than

    // comment out the line below

    // Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";

    System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();

    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite =
    new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);

    GridView1.RenderControl(htmlWrite);

    Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());

    Response.End();

}
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{

    // Confirms that an HtmlForm control is rendered for the
    //specified ASP.NET server control at run time.

}
```

Comment: this helped me work on the complete Export-To-Excel code. 

am just not so sure about keeping `VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)` empty though.

Answer (score 1):

```
public partial class exportgridtoexcel : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString.ToString());
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            GetData();
        }
    }
    public void GetData()
    {
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from EmpData", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetData();
        exporttoexcel("Report.xls", GridView1);
        GridView1 = null;
        GridView1.Dispose();



    }
    public void exporttoexcel(string filename,GridView gv)
    {
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);
        Response.ContentType = "applicatio/excel";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(); ;
        HtmlTextWriter htm=new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        gv.RenderControl(htm);
        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You're asking how to save the exported file... Your code puts the rendered contents of the gridview (HTML) into the Response. In this case your browser (client-side) will receive this response and pops-up a dialog asking where to save it. So your **browser** will save the file for you.

If you want to save it server side you must not put the rendered gridview into the response. Write it to a file on the local hard disc instead (like the answer above shows).

Remember that, in an environment other than your own development machine (i.e. a production environment), the ASP.NET worker process might not have enough access rights to write to the specified location on the hard disc. Here are a couple of answers that adresses that problem:

[ASP.net user account permissions](https://serverfault.com/questions/83194/asp-net-user-account-permissions-in-iis-7-on-windows-2008-server)
[ASP.NET + Access to the path is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219440/asp-net-access-to-the-path-is-denied)
[System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898939/system-unauthorizedaccessexception-access-to-the-path-is-denied)

Answer (score 0):

Folowed the link: [C# Excel file OLEDB read HTML IMPORT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238473/c-sharp-excel-file-oledb-read-html-import/11867494#11867494)

Use the `Extended Properties=\"HTML Import;HDR=No;IMEX=1 the select * from [tablename]`,
tablename is returned from `GetOleDbSchemaTable`.

Note: This would not load the normal excel. For that use `Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1\`, where table name will be with `$` sign.

Check sample code:
[Can't read excel file after creating it using File.WriteAllText() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920342/cant-read-excel-file-after-creating-it-using-file-writealltext-function/11867731#11867731)

Answer (score 0):

One another solution for this problem solved here : http://codentq.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/write-excel-file-from-dataset/

you have to get your grid view data in data set by method mention on this article : http://codentq.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/get-data-from-grid-to-datatable-or-dataset/

Answer (score -1):

first add EPPLUS reference library into application and add using OfficeOpenXml;

//business object class

class bocls
    {

```
    string name;

    public string NAME
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
    string id;

    public string ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }



    public bocls() { }
    public bocls(string name, string id)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;         

    }
```

//in export button click event

protected void lbtnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
            List<bocls> list6 =  new List<bocls>();
           //copy the grid view values into list
            list6 = (from row in dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
            from cell in row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
            select new 
            {
                //project into your new class from the row and cell vars.
            }).ToList();
    }
            ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage();
            var workSheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Products");
            var totalCols = GridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
            var totalRows = GridView1.Rows.Count;
            var headerRow = GridView1.HeaderRow;
            for (var i = 1; i <= totalCols; i++)
            {
                workSheet.Cells[1, i].Value = headerRow.Cells[i - 1].Text;
            }
            for (var j = 1; j <= totalRows; j++)
            {
                for (var i = 1; i <= totalCols; i++)
                {
                    var item = list6.ElementAt(j - 1);

                    workSheet.Column(1).Width = 13;
                    workSheet.Column(2).Width = 10;

                    workSheet.Cells[j + 1, i].Style.WrapText = true;

                    if (headerRow.Cells[i - 1].Text == "ID")
                        workSheet.Cells[j + 1, i].Value = item.GetType().GetProperty("id").GetValue(item, null);
                    else if (headerRow.Cells[i - 1].Text == "NAME")
                        workSheet.Cells[j + 1, i].Value = item.GetType().GetProperty("name").GetValue(item, null);

                    workSheet.Cells[j + 1, i].Value = workSheet.Cells[j + 1, i].Value.ToString().Replace("<br/>", "");
                }
            }
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {

                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                string filename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".xlsx";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=" + filename);
                excel.SaveAs(memoryStream);   
                //add your destination folder
                FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\karthi\Downloads\New folder\" + filename, FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write,FileShare.Write);
                memoryStream.WriteTo(fileStream);
                fileStream.Close();
                memoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                memoryStream.Close();
                memoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }

    }
```