# how to export data from datagrid to excel without images?

Tags: asp.net, excel, datagrid

I want to display,insert,update,delete in DataGrid (Asp.net and Sqlserver2008) and then i want to export data from datagrid to excel file.
[Table Structure](http://s17.postimage.org/445u9hl2n/image.jpg)

Default.aspx

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" EnableEventValidation="false"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>'A'</title>
    <style type="text`/css">`
     .Gridview
        {
            font-family: Verdana;
            font-size: 10pt;
            font-weight: normal;
            color: black;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ConfirmationBox(username) {

            var result = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete ' + username + ' Details?');
            if (result) {

                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvDetails" DataKeyNames="UserId,UserName" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
            CssClass="Gridview" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#61A6F8" ShowFooter="true" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true"
            HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvDetails_RowCancelingEdit"
            OnRowDeleting="gvDetails_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="gvDetails_RowEditing" 
            OnRowUpdating="gvDetails_RowUpdating"
            OnRowCommand="gvDetails_RowCommand" Height="275px" Width="530px">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnUpdate" CommandName="Update" runat="server" 
                            ImageUrl="~/Images/update.jpg" ToolTip="Update" Height="20px" Width="20px" />
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" 
                            ImageUrl="~/Images/Cancel.jpg" ToolTip="Cancel" Height="20px" Width="20px" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnEdit" CommandName="Edit" runat="server" 
                            ImageUrl="~/Images/Edit.jpg" ToolTip="Edit" Height="20px" Width="20px" />
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnDelete" CommandName="Delete" runat="server" 
                            ImageUrl="~/Images/delete.jpg" ToolTip="Delete" Height="20px" Width="20px" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnAdd" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/AddNewitem.jpg"
                            CommandName="AddNew" Width="30px" Height="30px" ToolTip="Add new User" ValidationGroup="validaiton" />
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UserName">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lbleditusr" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Username") %>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblitemUsr" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("UserName") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtftrusrname" runat="server" />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvusername" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtftrusrname"
                            Text="*" ValidationGroup="validaiton" />
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtcity" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("City") %>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblcity" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("City") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtftrcity" runat="server" />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvcity" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtftrcity"
                            Text="*" ValidationGroup="validaiton" />
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Designation">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtstate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Designation") %>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblstate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Designation") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtftrDesignation" runat="server" />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvdesignation" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtftrDesignation"
                            Text="*" ValidationGroup="validaiton" />
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>

<HeaderStyle BackColor="#61A6F8" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="lblresult" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="btn_Excel" runat="server" Text="Excel" 
            onclick="btn_Excel_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;uid=sa;pwd=sa123;database=Example1");
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindEmployeeDetails();
        }
    }
    protected void BindEmployeeDetails()
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Employee_Details", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        con.Close();
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            gvDetails.DataSource = ds;
            gvDetails.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(ds.Tables[0].NewRow());
            gvDetails.DataSource = ds;
            gvDetails.DataBind();
            int columncount = gvDetails.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
            gvDetails.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
            gvDetails.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
            gvDetails.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = columncount;
            gvDetails.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "No Records Found";
        }
    }
    protected void gvDetails_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        gvDetails.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        BindEmployeeDetails();
    }
    protected void gvDetails_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        int userid = Convert.ToInt32(gvDetails.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
        string username = gvDetails.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["UserName"].ToString();
        TextBox txtcity = (TextBox)gvDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtcity");
        TextBox txtDesignation = (TextBox)gvDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtstate");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Employee_Details set City='" + txtcity.Text + "',Designation='" + txtDesignation.Text + "' where UserId=" + userid, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        lblresult.ForeColor = Color.Green;
        lblresult.Text = username + " Details Updated successfully";
        gvDetails.EditIndex = -1;
        BindEmployeeDetails();
    }

    protected void gvDetails_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        gvDetails.EditIndex = -1;
        BindEmployeeDetails();
    }

    protected void gvDetails_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        int userid = Convert.ToInt32(gvDetails.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["UserId"].ToString());
        string username = gvDetails.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["UserName"].ToString();
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from Employee_Details where UserId=" + userid, con);
        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        if (result == 1)
        {
            BindEmployeeDetails();
            lblresult.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
            lblresult.Text = username + " details deleted successfully";
        }
    }

    protected void gvDetails_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            //getting username from particular row
            string username = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "UserName"));
            //identifying the control in gridview
            ImageButton lnkbtnresult = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("imgbtnDelete");
            //raising javascript confirmationbox whenver user clicks on link button
            if (lnkbtnresult != null)
            {
                lnkbtnresult.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return ConfirmationBox('" + username + "')");
            }
        }
    }

    protected void gvDetails_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName.Equals("AddNew"))
        {
            TextBox txtUsrname = (TextBox)gvDetails.FooterRow.FindControl("txtftrusrname");
            TextBox txtCity = (TextBox)gvDetails.FooterRow.FindControl("txtftrcity");
            TextBox txtDesgnation = (TextBox)gvDetails.FooterRow.FindControl("txtftrDesignation");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd =
                new SqlCommand("insert into Employee_Details(UserName,City,Designation) values('"
                    + txtUsrname.Text + "','" + txtCity.Text + "','" + txtDesgnation.Text + "')", con);
            int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            if (result == 1)
            {
                BindEmployeeDetails();
                lblresult.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
                lblresult.Text = txtUsrname.Text + " Details inserted successfully";
            }
            else
            {
                lblresult.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                lblresult.Text = txtUsrname.Text + " Details not inserted";
            }
        }
    }
    protected void btn_Excel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.gvDetails.AllowPaging = false;
        this.gvDetails.AllowSorting = false;
        this.gvDetails.EditIndex = -1;
        this.BindEmployeeDetails();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=MyList.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        StringWriter swriter = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hwriter = new HtmlTextWriter(swriter);
        gvDetails.RenderControl(hwriter);
        Response.Write(swriter.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
        //to Render Control
    }
}
```

My code works fine.
But my excel file looks like this
[Excel output](http://s16.postimage.org/huhsb6h45/image.jpg)

So i don't want the images in datagrid to be exported.
How can i do that.
Kindly reply.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411520/export-grid-view-to-excel-and-save-excel-file-to-folder

Comment: it doesn't help..i m getting the same result....what i want is to remove the images from my datagrid while exporting the data from datagrid to excel...

Comment: Why don't you export your `DataTable` or `DataView`, rather than exporting `GridView`? You can remove unnecessary columns while converting `DataTable` to `DataView`, and just export the required ones. I can provide you code for it, if you want.

Comment: @Rahell Khokhar: your answer doesn't recognize my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i got the solution (From a colleague).
Please vote my answer if its correct.
Explanation: 
1.We have to first make a temporary table.
2.Now add only the required column from datagrid.
3.Use temporary table to Export data in Excel.

Code:In the Button click call the function ExportUsersDataTable

```
protected void btn_Excel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){ExportUsersDataTable()}
```

The function definition is:

```
public void ExportUsersDataTable()
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Employee_Details", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();
    string sFilename = "UserToRoleMapping.xls";
    HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    response.Clear();
    response.Charset = ""; //string.Empty;
    response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + sFilename + "\"");
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
            GridView gvTemp = new GridView();

            //Temporary Table for changing the ExcelSheet Headers
            DataTable dtTemp = new DataTable();
            dtTemp.Columns.Add("User Id");
            dtTemp.Columns.Add("User Name");
            dtTemp.Columns.Add("City");
            dtTemp.Columns.Add("Designation");
            dtTemp.AcceptChanges();

            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    DataRow dr = dtTemp.NewRow();
                    dr["User Id"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["UserId"].ToString();
                    dr["User Name"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["UserName"].ToString();
                    dr["City"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["City"].ToString();
                    dr["Designation"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Designation"].ToString();
                    dtTemp.Rows.Add(dr);
                    dtTemp.AcceptChanges();
                }
            }

            if (dtTemp.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                gvTemp.DataSource = dtTemp;
                gvTemp.DataBind();
                gvTemp.RenderControl(htw);
                response.Write(sw.ToString());
            }
            response.End();
        }
    }
}
```